# Unity - Copy another object's Y location?

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I'm creating a Pong clone inside of Unity and was trying to figure how to copy another object (In this case being the Y co-od of the Ball Object) How would i go about doing this? I'm using vectors as my method of paddle movement and I want to create a public int AISpeed so that the AI paddle is a little slower in comparison

In my mind I assumed it was along the lines of:
**rightPaddle.location.y = pongBall.location.y**

How would I create this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that rightPaddle and pongBall are both game objects, your code would look something like the following:

```
Vector3 paddleOldPos = rightPaddle.transform.position;
Vector3 ballPos = pongBall.transform.position
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(paddleOldPos.x, ballPos.y, paddleOldPos.z);

rightPaddle.transform.position = newPos;
```

You can't modify a transform's position directly, you'll have to overwrite it, as above.

Hope that helps :-)